# Postgresql - Idle query keep open connections to all databases

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-12

I have a strange situation in my PostgreSQL server. I have the below idle query that keeps running in all databases in the server.

```
datid            | 1029662
datname          | ganar
pid              | 19022
usesysid         | 10
usename          | postgres
application_name | 
client_addr      | 
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | -1
backend_start    | 2023-08-27 10:10:23.265554+00
xact_start       | 
query_start      | 2023-08-27 10:18:07.886526+00
state_change     | 2023-08-27 10:18:07.886626+00
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
state            | idle
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 
query            | SELECT version();
backend_type     | client backend
```

If I tried to create a database named "test", it will have the same query running even without connecting to it via the "postgres" user.

```
datid            | 1887973
datname          | test
pid              | 19021
usesysid         | 10
usename          | postgres
application_name | 
client_addr      | 
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | -1
backend_start    | 2023-08-27 10:10:23.210437+00
xact_start       | 
query_start      | 2023-08-27 10:18:07.885979+00
state_change     | 2023-08-27 10:18:07.886143+00
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
state            | idle
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 
query            | SELECT version();
backend_type     | client backend
```

I've tried to kill this process but after 5 sec, it's getting created again.

Comment: The fact is, a client is connecting as the postgres user and doing SELECT version(). Now you need to track down what that client is.  Best guess some sort of monitoring program. I would start by looking at the Postgres log.

Comment: `backend_type     | client backend`, this shows you that some client is doing this.

Comment: Note that it is not the "idle query" that keeps the connection open. It is the client that forgets to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL server's ongoing idle query appears to be caused by a connection pooling system or an external application that is constantly connecting to your database. In order to find the PostgreSQL version, the query `SELECT version();` is frequently used. Start by looking at your application's source code, configuration settings, and any external scripts that might be opening connections as a first step in fixing issue. Verify that no unauthorised or redundant connections are being established. Check the setup of your connection pooling software if you use it to avoid having idle connections linger. To learn more about the source of these queries, you should also look through your PostgreSQL logs. The client application and host connected to these idle queries can be found using the `pg_stat_activity` view. To successfully resolve this, it is crucial to identify the source and change the related application or settings to stop irrational connections and queries from being made.

Comment: I don't have any app or script that's running with the postgres user. each app has it's user that have access to its database only. I checked the logs and didn't find anything suspicious. The weird thing is that when I try to create a brand new database and check its connection, I find the same query!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from the monitoring system, I've excluded the database from the monitoring system and worked fine. Thank you all.

Comment: Rather than not monitoring the database, fix the monitoring system so that it does not leak connections.

Comment: I don't need to monitor it as it's just a test database. So, I've excluded it from the monitoring system and kept the rest of the databases